# How to determine whether my application is active (has focus)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is there a way to tell whether my application is active i.e. any of its windows has .IsActive=true?

I'm writing messenger app and want it to flash in taskbar when it is inactive and new message arrives.

Comment: Override the form's OnActivate and OnDeactive methods.  Flashing buttons isn't the greatest user interface approach, consider a NotifyIcon instead.  But only show the balloon when there has been extended inactivity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Used P/Invoke and loop

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

private static bool IsActive(Window wnd)
{
    // workaround for minimization bug
    // Managed .IsActive may return wrong value
    if (wnd == null) return false;
    return GetForegroundWindow() == new WindowInteropHelper(wnd).Handle;
}

public static bool IsApplicationActive()
{
    foreach (var wnd in Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>())
        if (IsActive(wnd)) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Is this could only for check current window is active or not? Or also could bring the window to the front?

Comment: Could save the IntPtr returned by GetForegroundWindow and avoid calling on every loop iteration.

Answer (score 9):

You can subscribe to Main Window's [Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.activated.aspx) event, and then do whatever you want. Can you give it a try?

Answer (score 4):

You have the `Activated` and `Deactivated` events of `Application`.

If you want to be able to Bind to `IsActive` you can add a Property in `App.xaml.cs`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=IsActive,
                          Source={x:Static Application.Current}}"/>
```

of course you can also access this property in code like

```
App application = Application.Current as App;
bool isActive = application.IsActive;
```

*App.xaml.cs*

```
public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool m_isActive;
    public bool IsActive
    {
        get { return m_isActive; }
        private set
        {
            m_isActive = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsActive");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        Activated += (object sender, EventArgs ea) =>
        {
            IsActive = true;
        };
        Deactivated += (object sender, EventArgs ea) =>
        {
            IsActive = false;
        };
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the right idea but posted code that is unlikely to work.  OnStartup() is a VB.NET implementation detail, C# apps rarely use the WindowsFormsApplicationBase class.  Just override the OnActivate and OnDeactivate methods.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I'm not sure I understand what you mean here. If you want to get the startup arguments for example in a WPF app, you override OnStartup. Although I agree that overriding OnActivate/OnDeactivate is a prettier solution I see no reason for this not to work. Also, I didn't submit the answer before trying it and it runs just fine

Comment: @Hans Passant: I think you didn't read the tags well enough this time, this is WPF and not Windows Forms :)

Answer (score 3):

try this, override OnActivated method in your MainForm and do whatever you want

```
    protected override void OnActivated(EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO : Implement your code here.
        base.OnActivated(e);
    }
```

hop this help

Answer (score -3):

One way (may be there would be more better ways) can be to find the Active window through Windows API then find the process name of active window.

```
if(yourProcessName == ActiveWindowProcessName)
{
    //your window is in focus
}
```

Another way could be to keep a reference of all the windows and when you want to find out whether your app is active or not just iterate through all the windows and check `IsActive` value

Another way could be to use `OwnedWindows` property of MainWindow. Whenever you are creating a new window assign main window it's owner. Then you can iterate all the `OwnedWindows` of MainWindow and check whether any is active or not.(never tried this approach)

Comment: Why so complicated, I do not understand why shoud we go down to the process level when in the same time we have a complete infrastructure to check Application's Window state

Comment: I am not suggesting to use it I am telling all the possible ways