# Determine if current application is activated (has focus)

Tags: c#, .net

> Note: There's a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7049989/21475), but it's WPF-specific; this one is not.

How can I determine if the current application is activated (i.e. has focus)?

Comment: Are you talking about your personal windowsform application or arbitrary?

Comment: like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2183541/c-detecting-which-application-has-focus

Comment: Personal -- hence "current application" ;-)

Comment: @Code Monkey: Yes, except that I didn't want to have to intercept messages or add event listeners if possible (also, I think the accepted answer for that question would not work if there are two windows on different threads (with neither owning the other), but part of the same application -- and yes, I need to deal with that)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This works:

```
/// <summary>Returns true if the current application has focus, false otherwise</summary>
public static bool ApplicationIsActivated()
{
    var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (activatedHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
        return false;       // No window is currently activated
    }

    var procId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    int activeProcId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(activatedHandle, out activeProcId);

    return activeProcId == procId;
}


[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);
```

It has the advantage of being thread-safe, not requiring the main form (or its handle) and is not WPF or WinForms specific. It will work with child windows (even independent ones created on a separate thread). Also, there's zero setup required.

The disadvantage is that it uses a little P/Invoke, but I can live with that :-)

Comment: This may 'work with' child windows but it does not differentiate between them and their parents.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, that's the point. A child window is still part of the application. I guess by 'current application' I really meant 'current process'.

Comment: Reference "System.Runtime.InteropServices" for `DllImport`

Comment: And "using System.Diagnostics; "

Answer (score 13):

The solution I found which requires neither native calls nor requires handling events is to check [`Form.ActiveForm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.activeform?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Windows_Forms_Form_ActiveForm). In my tests, that was `null` when no window in the application was focused and otherwise non-null.

```
var windowInApplicationIsFocused = Form.ActiveForm != null;
```

Ah, this is specific to winforms. But that applies to my situation ;-).

Comment: This is an interesting one. An app I'm editing had code to steal focus from its own tool window on mouse-over of its main window, but this apparently occasionally also made it steal focus from other applications. Checking `Form.ActiveForm` looks like a promising way to prevent this.

Answer (score 11):

since it's likely that some element in your UI has contain focus for the form to be active try:

```
this.ContainsFocus
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.containsfocus(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This only works if you have a single form (and no dialog boxes, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

You can subscribe to [Main Window's Activated event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.activated.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

First get the handle either using:

IntPtr myWindowHandle;

```
myWindowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(Application.Current.MainWindow).Handle;
```

or

```
HwndSource source = (HwndSource)HwndSource.FromVisual(this);
myWindowHandle = source.Handle;
```

Then compare whethers it is the ForeGroundWindow:

```
if (myWindowHandle == GetForegroundWindow()) 
{
  // Do stuff!

}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

Comment: What if a child window is the foreground window? The application still has focus, but not the main window.

Comment: @cameron, true but you figured that much, so sad about the downvote :-) doesn't the criticism apply to the other suggested answers as well?

Comment: I didn't down- or up-vote anyone, but the "activated" answers would work as long as the main window is a parent (or grand-parent) of all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Handle the [Activated event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.activated.aspx) of your main application Form.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF the easiest way to check if a window is active is:

```
if(this.IsActive)
{
 //the window is active
}
```