# How do I see if my form is currently on top of the other ones? 

Tags: c#, winforms, topmost

Basically, how do I tell if my program is layered above all the other ones?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A fairly simple way is to P/Invoke [GetForegroundWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28VS.85%29.aspx) and compare the HWND returned to the application's form.Handle property.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class GFW
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        public bool IsActive(IntPtr handle)
        {
            IntPtr activeHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
            return (activeHandle == handle);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, from your form:

```
if (MyNamespace.GFW.IsActive(this.Handle))
{
  // Do whatever.
}
```

Comment: So this will be run instantly when it becomes the topmost form?

Comment: No, the code sample above just checks to see whether you have the foreground window. To execute code when you become the foreground window you'll have to use SetWinEventHook.

Comment: Thanks so much, I've taken an hours for search this solution on google but now you're my hero

Answer (score 1):

*You can use:*

```
if (GetForegroundWindow() == Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle)
{
     //do stuff
}
```

WINAPI imports (at class level):

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool GetForegroundWindow();
```

Assign a property to hold the value, and add the check to the form's GotFocus event through IDE, or after InitializeComponent();

e.g.:

```
//.....
InitalizeComponent();
this.GotFocus += (myFocusCheck);
//...

private bool onTop = false;

private void myFocusCheck(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    if(GetFore......){ onTop = true; }
}
```

Comment: Two problems - I need it to tell when it becomes the topmost window, and I don't know where to put the imports.

Answer (score 0):

If your window inherits form, you can check Form.Topmost property

Answer (score 0):

A good solution is given by this answer to an identical question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7162873/386091

```
/// <summary>Returns true if the current application has focus, false otherwise</summary>
public static bool ApplicationIsActivated()
{
    var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();
    if (activatedHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
        return false;       // No window is currently activated
    }

    var procId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
    int activeProcId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(activatedHandle, out activeProcId);

    return activeProcId == procId;
}


[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);
```

The currently accepted solution by Euric doesn't work if your program shows a dialog box or has detachable windows (like if you use a windows docking framework).