# How to enable mouse scrolling in my Console Application

Tags: c#

I am creating a Command Line tool in C#.
I can't scroll through my console application using mouse wheel.

How can I enable mouse wheel scroll in my Console . ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not as easy as a standard window app event as you need to hook in to the win32API. Here's a  guide on how to do it:

[Capturing mouse wheel events in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856386/capturing-mouse-wheel-events-in-console-application)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. If you want this, probably the best you can do is make a WinForms/WPF application with a single textbox (multiline) that has this feature automatically.