# C# - Switch between several instances of notepad with the mousewheel

Tags: c#, event-handling, mousewheel

i am kind of new to developing, so sorry for my (k)no(w)legde.

i want to save all instances of notepad in an Process[]

`public Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");`

and then iterate the array by using my mousewheel.

I've tried to use the `MouseWheelEventHandler`, but all examples i found were WindowsForms examples.

How do i solve this?

Comment: For console applications, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15856386/capturing-mouse-wheel-events-in-console-application) might be interesting.

Comment: So if you do not have a Winform application, which UI framework (WPF/UWP/Xamarin/MAUI/ASP.NET/.../...) do you use? Please add the relevant tag to your question.