# How to get Windows Active Window Handle using a Background Worker Service

Tags: c#, windows-services, backgroundworker

I'm developing a simple Background Worker service to run as a Windows service following [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/windows-service?pivots=dotnet-6-0).

The service will periodically log if certain applications are actively running on the users machines. Collected info includes: Machine Name, User Name, App Name, App Version, Is App Currently Focused?.

When I run the worker service's exe directly from windows, everything works fine; but when I create a service using the same exe, `Environment.UserName` is returning "System" and the user32.dll's `GetForegroundWindow()` function is not finding the active window (returning 0).

I learned that this is because the Windows service is run under a different user (System instead of the logged-in user)

I was able to solve the UserName problem by invoking a PowerShell cmdlet from within the service which grabbed the correct user name, but I don't seem to be able to do the same for `GetForegroundWindow()`.

Here are the methods I'm using to get the user name and check if the grabbed process's window is the foreground window ([inspired by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162834/determine-if-current-application-is-activated-has-focus)):

```
private static StringBuilder _outStream = new StringBuilder();
private static StringBuilder _errStream = new StringBuilder();
//Using the CliWrap library to invoke command line commands 
private static Command GetPSCommand()
        {
            _outStream.Clear();
            _errStream.Clear();
            var c = Cli.Wrap("PowerShell.exe")
                .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(_outStream))
                .WithStandardErrorPipe(PipeTarget.ToStringBuilder(_errStream))
                .WithValidation(CommandResultValidation.ZeroExitCode);
            return c;
        }

        public static async Task<string> GetUserNameAsync()
        {
            var pscmd = @"(Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem).Username";
    
            var cmd = GetPSCommand().WithArguments(pscmd);

            await cmd.ExecuteAsync();

            if (_errStream.Length > 0)
                Log.Error(_errStream.ToString());

            var username = _outStream.ToString();
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) ? "NotFound" : username.Split('\\').LastOrDefault()!;
        }

        
public static bool IsInFocus(Process proc)
        {
            var activatedHandle = GetForegroundWindow();

            if (activatedHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                return false;       // No window is currently activated
            }

            var procId = proc.Id;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(activatedHandle, out var activeProcId);

            return activeProcId == procId;
        }
```

I am creating the service using this code snippet:

```
var cmd = Cli.Wrap("sc.exe")
        .WithStandardOutputPipe(PipeTarget.ToDelegate(Log.Debug))
        .WithStandardErrorPipe(PipeTarget.ToDelegate(Log.Error))
        .WithValidation(CommandResultValidation.ZeroExitCode)
    ;

var installCmd = cmd.WithArguments(new[]
                { "create",
                    ServiceName,
                    $"binPath={executablePath}",
                    "start=auto",
                }
);
```

I also tried to create the service using `obj = "MyUserName"` and `password = "MyPassword"` to see if that would change anything, but couldn't get it to work (err: User does not exist or wrong password).